# 5 seemingly unrelated words, the answer is in the form of a single letter

Tags: word, word-property

Here's a real stumper:

There are 5 words:

QUOTE

TRUE

NURSE

SPUR

SLIM

From these 5 words, there is a connection that will reveal a single letter, what is it?

Comment: We may need a hint.

Answer (score 5):

I have this bizarre theory that it might be the letter

> M

The words are related through

> ”Brain Damage” by Eminem.

Here’s how:

> The first verse features a discussion between Mathers and the school NURSE.
>
>  The second verse QUOTEs a school bullying incident that apparently gave Mathers brain damage. It appears that at least the part of there being a bully named D’Angelo Bailey is TRUE: the song SPURred a lawsuit by that very same bully. The case received some attention, since the judge dropped the lawsuit, and [even a couple of rhymes.](https://www.rollingstone.com/music/news/judge-drops-eminem-rap-20031020)

This all brings us back to the single letter by the following path:

> Mathers -> SLIM Shady -> Eminem -> M&M -> M

..Yeah, I’m probably overthinking this by at least a factor of ten.

Comment: +1. Just because I read EMINEM in there and I am a fanboy :)

Answer (score 3):

My letter is:

> $\pi$

Because:

> The letters used are E, I, and 10 consecutive letters from L-U. Using $e$, $i$, and the digits 1 and 0, you can add $\pi$ to form $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$.

Comment: But Pi isn't a letter in the standard alphabet, sadly.

Answer (score 3):

This puzzle's been bugging me for a while, so I thought I'd take a crack at it.

I think the letter is

> l

Which is a

> lower-case "L"

Going word by word, you can construct a simple representation of each of them using it.

QUOTE

> Quotation mark(s) **"** look like two tiny "l"s.

TRUE

> The equals symbol **=** looks like two "l"s on top of each other.

NURSE

> The symbol for a Hospital **+** looks like two "l"s, crossed.

SPUR

> A simple spur **x** looks like two "l"s, crossed.

SLIM

> A single "**l**" is pretty slim--as slim as letters go!

An argument could be made for the answer being

> upper-case "I"

but that is a letter that appears in a clue word, while

> lower-case "L"

does not.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is

> A

Because

> 'A', although being a fairly common letter does not occur in any of these of this words. Also 'A' is the only vowel not present in these words.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure... The answer could be

> U

Because

> 1. The letter "u" appears 4 times, which is uncommon in English.
>  2. The letter counts produce two individual "dots" and one "line", which is morse code for "u":
>  a
>  b
>  c
>  d
>  e    ...
>  f
>  g
>  h
>  i    .
>  j
>  k
>  l    .
>  m    .
>  n    .
>  o    .
>  p    .
>  q    .
>  r    ...
>  s    ...
>  t    ..
>  u    ....
>  v
>  w
>  x
>  y
>  z

Comment: I really like this line of thought, the letter frequency is something I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be..

> **Y**.

QUOTE

```
Got nothing yet.
```

TRUE

> True/false can also be displayed as **Y**/N.

NURSE

```
Got nothing yet.
```

SPUR

> If you look at a spur off of a boot from the top, it closely resembles the letter **Y**.

SLIM

> The letter **Y** starts out wide and gets slimmer the further you go down.